# Railing accusation(s)?

Tags: 1-peter, 2-peter, jude

> 1 Peter 3:9:  Not rendering evil for evil, or **railing for railing**: but contrariwise blessing; knowing that ye are thereunto called, that ye should inherit a blessing.

> 2 Peter 2:11: Whereas angels, which are greater in power and might, bring not railing accusation against them before the Lord.

> Jude_1:9: Yet Michael the archangel, when contending with the devil he disputed about the body of Moses, **durst not bring against him a railing accusation**, but said, The Lord rebuke thee.

Do these scriptures/statements Forbid (preclude, prohibit, rule out, condemn) Christians from bringing forth any accusation(s) at all against others even when the accusation is clearly, verifiably true? or is the word "railing" the definitive qualifier? In other words, does the word "railing" imply and prohibit only untrue, false, unverifiable accusations, falsely maligning accusations?

For example, if a person (even those in authority: including Political Leaders) commits a crime/a sin/lies, etc. which is true & verifiable and is harmful to others, do these scriptures prohibit us (Christians) from "bringing forth" (speaking of, accusing, etc.)?

Comment: Since this is essentially a question about λοιδορίας [Strong 3059](https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_3059.htm) 1 Timothy 5:14, 1 Peter 3:9 and 1 Peter 3:9 again, I suggest it be asked on SE-BH.

Comment: Geremia had a good answer here about "Railing" https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/73730/according-to-the-catholic-church-is-it-sinful-to-address-someone-who-is-transgen/73738#73738  Could you improve this question by turning the title into a sentence with the form of a question?